# Windows Console Applications VS2105 C# - Using JSON Data

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have at times made it my life's work to avoid API's at all costs (that's a debate for another day) but the time is arriving for this to change, a few months ago I got started on creating an API for my applications, and thanks to this very website, it's worked a charm.

So now I'm creating a simple Windows Console Application, it should do nothing more than get API Data then submit to a database for the primary application to use at a later date.

So far so good or so I thought.

This is what I came up with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pair = "xxx/xxx";
        string apiUrl = "http://someURL" + pair;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readerStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
        string json = readerStream.ReadToEnd();
        readerStream.Close();
        var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
        Console.WriteLine("Pair : " + (string)jo["pair"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Open : " + (string)jo["openPrice"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Close : " + (string)jo["closePrice"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Vol : " + (string)jo["vol"]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Now this works FANTASTIC for the primary source, but when I change the source (eventually it will be multi source) it fails to work.

After some investigation, it seems the slightly different responses are the culprit.

API Return looks like this

```
{
  "ip":"1.1.1.1","country_code":"AU","country_name":"Australia",
  "region_code":"VIC","region_name":"Victoria","city":"Research",
  "zip_code":"3095","time_zone":"Australia/Melbourne","latitude":-37.7,
  "longitude":145.1833,"metro_code":0
}
```

The return for an alternative source looks like this

```
{
  "success":true,"message":"",
  "result":[
    {"MarketName":"BITCNY-BTC","High":8000.00000001,"Low":7000.00000000,
     "Volume":0.02672075, "Last":7000.00000000,"BaseVolume":213.34995000,
     "TimeStamp":"2017-02-09T08:38:22.62","Bid":7000.00000001,"Ask":9999.99999999,
     "OpenBuyOrders":14,
     "OpenSellOrders":20,"PrevDay":8000.00000001,"Created":"2015-12-11T06:31:40.653"
    }
   ]
}
```

As we can see the second return is structured differently, and for this feed I've been unable to work this out, clearly my code works, kind of, and clearly it doesn't.

I've looked about on the net and am still no closer to a solution, partly I don't know what I'm really asking and secondly google only wants to talk webAPI.

If there is someone who can point me in the right direction, I don't want the work done for me per say that solves nothing, I have got to learn to do this one way or another.

Comment: "Slightly" different? These appear to be unrelated responses. Parsing these will return different data. *Your application* should be able to parse the different results and transform them to a common one if needed. In *this* case though, there is nothing common. BTW what does this question have to do with Visual Studio, Web API, Google or console applications?

Comment: Its VS and Console cos thats what it is a Windows Console Application done with VS, i dont use these places much im doing the best i can to provide the information needed for some help. LIke i said i dont really know what im asking, i have to means to produce a partial result but not a complete result. The api quotes are purly to demonstrate the diffrence im struggling with. Since all the APIs i plan to use are stuctured the same as those 2 examples.

Comment: PS you could halve your code just by using `HttpClient` and `GetStringAsync`. It's also safer - your code forgets to dispose of the objects. An undisposed response is an *open* connection to the server

Comment: in other words, nothing. Please clean up the post and ask a *specific* question. You posted two completely unrelated strings - one is geographic information the other pricing data. What "partial result" can you produce from this? They have *nothing* in common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your strings are unrelated. You won't be able to perform the same actions on both JSON strings because they're different.

Your best bet is to work with `Deserialization` to objects, which is converting a JSON string into an object and working with `properties` instead of JObject literals.

Putting your first JSON string into `Json2Csharp.com`, this class structure was produced:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public string country_code { get; set; }
    public string country_name { get; set; }
    public string region_code { get; set; }
    public string region_name { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string zip_code { get; set; }
    public string time_zone { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public int metro_code { get; set; }
}
```

You could then make some adjustments to your code to extract the `HTTP request` functionality, assuming that you'll only be working with JSON strings in this instance, and then simply deserialized the JSON to an object.

An example of a `WebRequest()` method would be:

```
private static string WebRequest(string UrlToQuery)
{
    using(WebClient client = new WebClient)
    {
        return client.DownloadString(UrlToQuery);
    }
}
```

(Make sure you catch any errors and deal with unexpected responses, I'll leave that up to you!)

You can then call this method like so:

```
string JsonResponse = WebRequest(apiUrl);
```

and `deserialize` to an object of type `RootObject` like so:

```
RootObject deserializedString = JsonConvert.Deserialize<RootObject>(JsonResponse);
```

You'll then be able to perform something like:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Country name: {deserializedString.country_name}");
```

Which will print the value of the `country_name` property of your `deserializedString` object.

Comment: Ohh i see i think.

My approach is floored, based on the above (not tried it yet) ill need to provide a handler (bear with me) for each API endpoint I want to use, since each endpoint is likely to offer a slightly different response. The problem itself here is my understanding of this. Ill get to work and see what i can come up with and will report back with the finito product. Thx Jay

Comment: Yeah you'll need a new class structure for individual responses, or you can dynamically deserialize the JSON string but then you'll have to build handlers for each different type of response. Deserializing to objects just makes life easier, plus it allows you to build collections of them easily and work with the data.

Comment: For some reason i cant accept your responce as the answer.

Ive updated the OP for my inelegant solution

Comment: Found the accept as answer button staring me in the face :)